# Taking two excel sheets in same workbook and finding same values in certain columns and copy data from other columns

Tags: excel, csv

I have two sheets in the same excel workbook, sheet 1 and sheet 2. There are thousands of entries in each sheet but there is one column called username in both sheets. I have 3 columns(columns 3, 4, 11) in sheet 2 that need to be added to be added with the headers to sheet 1. Sheet 1 already has 10 columns with data. Sheet 2 has 13 columns of data. So preferably be able to add 3 more columns to sheet 1.

If there is a match in both the username cell from sheet 1(column 5) and sheet 2(column 11), add the new columns/data(columns 3, 4, and 11) from sheet 2 to sheet 1. I believe I need to use Vlookup and/or Match function in excel? I'm new to using excel so this is all new to me.

Any help would be very appreciated! Thank you.

Here is an example of sheet 1:

```
column1  column2  column3  column4  username  column6......column10  
data    data      data      data     joe       data          data     
data    data      data      data     rick      data          data     
..       ..        ...       ..      ..         ..           ..
```

Example of sheet 2:

```
col1   col2   col3   col4   col5   col6   col7   col8   col9   col10  username   col12   col13

data   data   data   data   data   data   data   data   data   data   peter       data     data
data   data   data   data   data   data   data   data   data   data   gary       data     data   
..     ..     ..     ..     ..     ..     ..     ..     ..     ..     ..         ..         ..
```

I tried to match the usernames and list corresponding data for each username from sheet2 column K and L(col 11 and 12). But I am getting #NA. Whats wrong with this?

```
=INDEX(Sheet2!K$3:L$14119,MATCH(K3,Sheet2!K$3:K$14119),0, FALSE)
```

Comment: You will need to use the INDEX/MATCH functions.  There are many tutorials on the web and quick google will give you many examples.

Comment: Many of the tutorials only give examples of using INDEX/MATCH to search for one specific entry in a cell. Since I have a bunch of usernames(over 10,000 and continue to grow), I want to be able to have a function that matches the names and then bring the data from sheet 2.

Comment: You would have separate formula in each cell the references a different column as the return value.

Comment: please put your code attempt(s) in the body of the question itself, where it can be more properly formatted and marked down for legibility. You can [EDIT](http://stackoverflow.com/posts/38337010/edit) your question and include these details.

Comment: `=INDEX(Sheet2!L$3:L$14119,MATCH($E3,Sheet2!$K$3:$K$14119,0))`

Comment: Wow, Thank you so much Scott! That works exactly how needed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to Scott, here is what I was trying to do. I guess I was kind of close.   =INDEX(Sheet2!L$3:L$14119,MATCH($E3,Sheet2!$K$3:$K$14119,0))